# Windows in Gnome Metacity don't have shadows

Tags: gnome

I installed the *gnome-panel* utility, but when I switched to *Gnome Metacity*, windows there appeared to have no shadows. Here's a picture:

[image]

It's actually very difficult to work against white backgrounds with windows that don't have clearly delineated borders. I'm wondering if there is a way to somehow get those drop shadows back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be only a problem in the new Ubuntu 15.10. I don't think there's any simple way to fix it. So, I just reverted my computer back to Ubuntu 14.04.